# How to get start date of current year in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I don't know how to use `NSDate` or `NSCalendar` in this condition.
Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Every year starts with 1st of January, isn't it?

Comment: Actually i am not getting your question can you please describe your problem in very briefly.

Comment: Actually I get the first date of the current year. i.e for current year 1-1-2015. Understood?

Comment: yes and if the year is 2015 then current date is 1-1-2015 if the year is 2016 then the date is 1-1-2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(NSDate *)getFirstDateOfCurrentYear
 {
  //Get current year
  NSDate *currentYear=[[NSDate alloc]init];
  currentYear=[NSDate date];
  NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
  NSString *currentYearString = [formatter1 stringFromDate:currentYear];

  //Get first date of current year
  NSString *firstDateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10 01-01-%@",currentYearString];
  NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"hh dd-MM-yyyy"];
  NSDate *firstDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
  firstDate = [formatter2 dateFromString:firstDateString];

  return firstDate;
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done much cleaner than the other answers:

```
NSDate *startOfYear;

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear startDate:&startOfYear interval:0 forDate:[NSDate date]];
```

`startOfYear` now holds midnight at January 1st of the current year.

Comment: Definitely the cleanest answer. It doesn't reflect super well on the NSDate API that people have to work so hard to come up with solutions to this perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setDay:1];
self.currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
int m = components.month;
int y = components.year;
int d = components.day;


NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd"];
NSDate *firstDateOfMonth = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ 01",y,m]];
NSDate *firstDateOfYear = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 01 01",y]];
```

Comment: @MihirOza i didn't get you

Comment: Thanks  I got My Answer from you and @BrittoThomas.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:now];
components.month = 1;
components.day = 1;
NSDate *firstDayOfYear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: Hi bro.is is possible to get last date of year?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel you can get the first day of year and then minus 1 day from that date

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSDate *)firstDateOfCurrentYear
 {

     NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [fmt setDateFormat:@"YYYY-01-01 00:00:00 0000"];
     NSString *dateStr = [fmt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     [fmt setDateFormat: @"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
     NSDate *firstDate = [fmt dateFromString:dateStr];
     return firstDate;
 }
```